# Regex, how to match all urls but one?

Tags: regex

My Regex skills a minimum, I have been trying for a while now to get this to work:

I need to match all urls in one domain, but one (the login one).

Example:

Match: domain.com/ANYTHING-GOES-HERE

but

Not Match: domain.com/login

I don't actually need to match the domain.com part because that's always the same, what comes after it.

I have tried:

```
(?!\/login)\/.*

\/.*[^login]
```

Neither one seems to work as desired.

**Update:**

I should have explained that this is done in PHP. I don't have control over the actual code that runs the regex, but I do have control over how many regex I can have. So I could have one regex that matches everything, and then have one regex that matches or not matches "/login"

Comment: I love when people down vote my question without explaining why.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I wouldn't use regex: I would do it in two steps:
1. match the beginning of the url to: `domain.com`
2. check that the rest of the url doesn't match `/login`

Comment: @alfasin, you can always do regex in multiple steps to simplify things ;)

Comment: @bluebaby the question is "how many steps". If it's minimal and the code is readable and efficient - then you shouldn't use regex (IMHO).

Comment: This for url redirection done in php, the only option I have regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
// javascript
r = /domain\.com\/(?!login).+/
r.test("domain.com/ANYTHING-GOES-HERE") // true
r.test("domain.com/login") // false
```

This also rejects `"domain.com/login/foobar"`, if you want it to be accepted, modify the regex to be

```
r = /domain\.com\/(?!login$).+/
```